# How to remove backslash("\") from string having ASCII string combination in java

Tags: java

Input string is `"ABC\1067546161"`

I want to remove "\" backslash and get digits only from the string but we are getting string with ascii value.Result String is ABCF7546161 after print.

Please suggest some solution.

> Input String is `ABC\1067546161`
>
> Expected result is `1067546161`

Comment: You can't do it. The String literal itself is being stored as `ABCF7546161` and not `"ABC\1067546161"`. There is not `\106` in the input String itself (when you print it)

Comment: Can you escape the "\" when creating the string?

Comment: You have to escape "\". Otherwise it will always be interpreted as an ASCII code. Just take a look at this image and you will see what I mean [ASCII Table](http://www.electronicdeveloper.de/Images/ASCII-Tabelle1.PNG). the octal number 106 refers to F. When you print "\106" you also get "F" as a result

Comment: I just learned that the hard way myself lol

Comment: I can't do it because i am getting it from some other system. Is there any solution to remove \ from string.

Answer (score 2):

May be something like this 
`"ABC\1067546161".replaceAll("[a-zA-Z\\]", "")`

Comment: please explain why you downgraded me

Comment: Because it doesn't work. Print the String before replacing

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 8
[a-zA-Z\]
        ^
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.String.replaceAll(Unknown Source)
 at demos.Sample.main(Sample.java:8)

Comment: @ManojKumar, try this one in java "ABC\1067546161".replaceAll("[a-zA-Z\\\\\]", "")

Comment: This type of String getting from waffel library so that i can't change it. if any solution of reference you have then please suggest me.

Comment: @ManojKumar, I do not get what you want to say. Strings in Java are immutable, so you can not change them. But you receive this string as a response value, so you can easily perform this operation and receive new value without unnecessary symbols.

Answer (score 2):

I think this could work, but the code is ugly as hell..

```
    String word = "ABC\1067546161";
    char badChar = word.charAt(3);
    String[] arr = word.split(Character.toString(badChar));
    System.out.println(Integer.toOctalString(badChar) + arr[1]);
```

You only mentioned one string in the question, but on several cases, this would most likely not work.

Comment: There are ways to make this shorter, i believe, but as for now i'll have you do that for yourself.

Comment: Nope, this won't work. As @TheLostMind pointed out, the String is converted as soon as you assign it so the charAt(3) will return F.

Comment: @Aurasphere This does work. I have tested it myself. I split it at F, then print the ascii code (Octal code: 107) of the F and the 2. array object

Comment: @HåvardNygård - Though this one works, I woudn't suggest using this approach. What if the String already had `F` in it?

Comment: @HåvardNygård I'm sorry, I've missed the octal conversion in the System.out. This works indeed.

Comment: @TheLostMind I already pointed out that this is ugly. But if it atleast works for this case, its better than nothing.

Comment: @HåvardNygård - IMO *ugly* means something that works correctly but is bad (in terms of readability, maintainability or needs too much code). But hey, thats my definition :)

Comment: @TheLostMind we are heading a bit off topic, but i think its exactly what this code is, even in you definition :p It works, but needs to maintained for each case. ;p

Answer (score 1):

As @TheLostMind pointed out in a comment, you can't replace the backslash directly because the String is created with that value.

The only way to do that is manipulate the input itself and convert it into a byte array instead of a String. Then you can call the String constructor that takes a byte[] as argument and it won't be converted.

Once you have that, you can use a regex to remove the part you don't want as others suggested. Here's the code I've used to test this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Input manipulation.
    byte[] input = {'A','B','C','\\','1','0','6','7','5','4','6','1','6','1'};
    String string = new String(input);
    System.out.println(string);

    // Splitting.
    String[] result = string.split("\\\\");
    System.out.println(result[1]);
}
```